# Why does this if statement cause a syntax error

Tags: python, syntax

I am trying to set up an elif statement , where if the user hits the enter key the code will continue , however i am getting constant syntax errors

```
GTIN = 0
while True:
    try:
        GTIN = int(input("input your gtin-8 number:"))
        if len(str(GTIN)) == 8:
            break
        else:
            print("make sure the length of the barcode is 8")
        elif:
            GTIN=(""):
```

Comment: The order must be `if` then (zero or more) `elif` then lastly `else`. Also `elif` must have a condition to check the same way `if` does.

Comment: `else` must be the last clause, and `elif` must have a test.

Comment: You have no `except` case in your code.

Comment: What did you expect the code to produce?

Comment: `try` needs an `except` or `finally` clause

Comment: The `if` is one of the few parts in this code that's not wrong. Please include a [mcve] including expected behaviour and the complete traceback.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `else` before `elif`. The other problem, you must add `except` in your `try`.

```
GTIN = 0
while True:
  GTIN = int(input("input your gtin-8 number:"))
  if len(str(GTIN)) == 8:
    print("OK: %s" % GTIN)
    break
  else:
    print("make sure the length of the barcode is 8")
```

**Edit:** You don't need the elif. If input length is 8 OK, else do again.

**Edit2:** Don't need `try except` too.
*ps: print("") if you use python 3*

Comment: still produces `SyntaxError`.